# I am trying to find brier score of survival data using risk regression pacakge, but its giving an error

Tags: r, auc, cox-regression, survival

```
xy = Score(list(cox_ph), formula=Surv(time,status)~1,data=cox.train, metrics=c("brier","auc"), null.model=FALSE,times=time.int,debug = TRUE)
```

Extracted test set and prepared output object.

Trained the model(s) and extracted the predictions
merged the weights with input for performance metrics
added weights to predictions.

> Error in sindex(ind.controls[controls.index1 | controls.index2], 0) :
> missing data

I have tried debugging but its not giving the exact reason.